# C# Create 3 arrays and fill the third array with the two other arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to create three arrays. One is int and the others are decimal. Every arrays can have space for three items. ProductPrice(decimal) array need to be filled with product prices. ProductAmount(int) need to be filled with amount of the products. ProductTotalPrice(decimal) need to be filled with the result of multiplication which is executed with the items of two other arrays. In the end I need to print product names and total prices just like it's shown below:

Product 1: 9.90

Product 2: 77.0

Product 3: 95.50

Here's some kind of a not working code but I can't figure out how I could finish the task.

```
 using System;
class calculation
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal[] productPrice;
        decimal[] productTotalPrice;
        productPrice = new decimal[3];
        int[] productAmount = { Product_1, Product_2, Product_3 };
        productTotalPrice = new decimal[3];
        productPrice[0] = 9.90m;
        productPrice[1] = 77.0m;
        productPrice[2] = 95.50m;
        productTotalPrice[0] = productAmount[0] * productPrice[0];
        Console.WriteLine(productTotalPrice[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: when did you set the value for Product_1? and what do you mean by "not" working? did it give you the wrong answer?

Comment: where is Product_1,Product_2,Product_3 comes from? It must be `int` and assigned before multiplication.

Comment: What's wrong about a simple for loop?

Comment: In the "real world", you probably shouldn't work with three separate arrays, but have *one* type that holds the relevant data together. For example `public class Product { public decimal Price { get;set; } public int Amount { get;set; } public decimal TotalPrice { get { return Price * Amount; } } }` and then maybe have *one* array with the three instances of `Product`.

Comment: And why use arrays in new code?

Comment: @adrianm - you mean my suggestion? Yes, a list would probably more flexible.

Comment: I need to have two arrays and add the results to the third array. It may not be the best way but the task tells me to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
  decimal Product1=9.90

decimal  Product2=77.0

decimal  Product3=95.50
decimal[] productPrice;
    decimal[] productTotalPrice;
    productPrice = new decimal[3];
    decimal[] productAmount = { Product1, Product2, Product3 };
    productTotalPrice = new decimal[3];
    productPrice[0] = 9.90;
    productPrice[1] = 77.0;
    productPrice[2] = 95.50;
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        productTotalPrice[i]=productAmount[i] * productPrice[i];

    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(productTotalPrice[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Why would you separate the loop for computation and writing to the console? will give the same output

Comment: Just to differentiate between calculation and output although both can be done in one loop

Comment: The name 'Product_1' does not exist in the current context. I had the same problem before and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I added ; to the values you defined in the first three lines and I got this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'. I need to use integer with productAmount array because the task says so.

Comment: make both array of decimal

Comment: And after fixing the code like you said it prints out values 63.3616, 5184.00 and 9980,0100 which are totally different in the comparison with the values it's need to print(check my first post).

Comment: actually it multiply the productAmount array index value with productprice  array index value

Comment: please specify both array values ?

Comment: I changed Product1 etc to int and I added the amount of 1 product each. I also changed ProductAmount back to int. The Result is right but I need to figure out how to print like "Product 1: 9,90 \n Product 2: 77,0" etc. And when this works I need to paste the code to the site where I study this lesson if the code goes through.

Comment: Use this statment in console.writeline for output like this
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Product "+(i+1)+" "productTotalPrice[i]);

    }

Comment: Okay, I got it working. Not sure if the code was just like the task wanted me to do it but at least it looks like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to do this:

```
var productPrice  = new [] {1.34m, 5.24m, 12.54m, 16.99m};
var productAmount = new [] {4, 2, 6, 1};

var productTotalPrice = productPrice.Zip(productAmount, (price, amount) => price*amount).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", productTotalPrice));
```

Comment: There's something wrong because I got this error: 'decimal[]' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @HateB You need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the code file in order to use Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some values for `Product_1`, `Product_2` and `Product_3`. Let it be `120`, `150`, `10` respectively, Let me rename the array `productAmount` as `productQuantity` Since amount is little bit confusing with price. The you can try the following LINQ to do your task:

It will get each element from the `productQuantity` array and multiply with the corresponding element in the `productPrice` array. Finally we assign the result to the `productTotalPrice`.

```
decimal[] productPrice = new decimal[3];
productPrice[0] = 9.90m;
productPrice[1] = 77.0m;
productPrice[2] = 95.50m;
int[] productQuantity = { 120, 150, 10 };
decimal[] productTotalPrice = productQuantity.Select((x, K) => x * productPrice[K]).ToArray();
```

Comment: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: include `using System.Linq;`